# grpc-java server shuts down immediately

Tags: grpc

I have followed all the instructions to quickstart grpc-java tutorial from the following link:

```
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples but the command
../gradlew installDist
```

gives build successful but when I run the server it shows the result as follows:

pradnya@pradnya-VirtualBox:~/grpc-java/examples$ ./build/install/grpc-examples/bin/hello-world-server
Sep 07, 2015 6:36:21 PM io.grpc.examples.helloworld.HelloWorldServer start
INFO: Server started, listening on 50051
*** shutting down gRPC server since JVM is shutting down
*** server shut down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recent change (from Thursday, Sep 2nd) broke the example. A fix is to add a `server.awaitTermination()` at the end of the `start()` method, which will prevent the JVM from exiting. You'll also need to mark `start()` and `main()` as `throws InterruptedException`. I made [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/967) to track updating the example.